# Git won't merge branches because of untracked files

Tags: git

I was working on a git branch other than the master, and when I finished, I wanted to merge it with the master branch, but I got this error

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        frontend/debug.log
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
Updating 685bd2c..fb9cfb1
```

But when I tried to remove it by right-click and then delete, it gave me error saying it's busy or locked. I cannot even checkout the branch I wanted to merge now, basically giving me the same error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Close your `frontend` application and try again - and any editors which have that file open.

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a git question. Something is locking a file on your machine and you can't delete it. Close the things that are possibly locking it, or use a tool to see *what* is locking it (which would be OS specific). Or, you can usually reboot and then delete the file before you open your other apps too.